# Mystery space between elements despite use of borders only with border-sizing: border-box

Tags: css, html

So I can't figure out why setting the div to 55% and the img to 45% results in the image shifting to the next line. Here's the HTML:

```
<section class="explanation-paragraphs-section">
    <div class="explanation-paragraphs-div">
        <h2>blah blah blah</h2>
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
    <img class="explanation-paragraphs-right-img" src="./img/office-building.jpg">
</section>
```

I've used normalize.css for resets. The relevant CSS is as follows:

```
p {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

section.explanation-paragraphs-section {
    max-width: 1000px;
    min-width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto 2rem auto;
}

div.explanation-paragraphs-div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1.5rem 0 0 0;
    width: 55%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

div.explanation-paragraphs-div p {
    margin: 1.5rem 0 0 0;
}

div.explanation-paragraphs-div h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

section.explanation-paragraphs-section img {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 44.5%;
    border-top: 1.5rem solid transparent;
    vertical-align: top;
}

img.explanation-paragraphs-left-img {
    border-right: 1.5rem solid transparent;
}

img.explanation-paragraphs-right-img {
    border-left: 1.5rem solid transparent;
}
```

Setting the width of the img to 44.5% is a workable hack, but I can't figure what would be contributing any additional width to make it so that setting the img's width to 45% causes the img to shift to the next line.

Comment: unless you have absolutely no space between the elements (ie, `</div><div>`), `inline-block` has intrinsic spacing between elements. Take a look at [this method of creating grids using `inline-block`](http://www.barrelny.com/blog/text-align-justify-and-rwd/) to get an idea of what you can do to mitigate this.

Comment: Okay, I didn't realize the "no white space" thing applied to items other than things like <li>, etc. Thank you!

Comment: Just a "meta" suggestion.  Your title isn't very usefully for people searching for solutions to a similar problem.  I would recommend updating the title to something more descriptive of the actual issue.

Comment: “Solved” is not part of a good *question* title. The title now seems to be an answer to an unknown question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the line break after the div, before the image:

```
<section class="explanation-paragraphs-section">
    <div class="explanation-paragraphs-div">
        <h2>blah blah blah</h2>
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
    </div><img class="explanation-paragraphs-right-img" src="./img/office-building.jpg">
</section>
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/seancannon/7Bhy5/

Answer (score 0):

Like `inline` elements, the white spaces and line breaks in `HTML` between `inline-block` elements will be considered as a single white space.

You'll either have to remove these, or set the parent elements `font-size` to `0` - which is in most cases not a practical solution.

Instead of using `inline-block` you can `float` the `<div>` to `left` and `<img>` to `right`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/L5dcB/)

Or if ancient browser support is not an issue, you can apply `display:flex` on their container

Answer (score 0):

Think of inline-block elements that are next to each other as other inline elements that are next to each other. For example, some spans next to each other with spaces in the code such as:

```
<span>Hi</span> <span>There</span> <span>Friend</span>
```

Render like this:

Hi There Friend

Whereas some spans next to each other WITHOUT spaces that are coded this way:

```
<span>Hi</span><span>There</span><span>Friend</span>
```

Render like this:

HiThereFriend

Your inline-block elements that are wedged next to each other show that same white-space because your code has a line-break (interpreted as white space when rendered). If you fit your `div` and your `img` without white-space in your code, that extra rendered space should go away.

```
<div class="explanation-paragraphs-div">
        <h2>blah blah blah</h2>
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
    </div><img class="explanation-paragraphs-right-img" src="./img/office-building.jpg">
         ^^
```

Note the absence of white-space between the `div` and `img` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of those looking at the issue of removing inline-block whitespace, the option of removing line breaks between code blocks is not always practical, especially in situations like blocks being created by a CMS. Setting font-size to 0 is also very problematic. Here's a link to a pen that demonstrates a much more useful CSS fix: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/BfIun/